# using loops or lapply in R

Tags: r, for-loop, plyr, lapply

I'm trying to iteratively loop through subsets of an R df but am having some trouble. df$A contains values from 0-1000. I'd like to subset the df based on each unique value of df$A, manipulate that data, save it as a newdf, and then eventually concatenate (rbind) the 1000 generated newdf's into one single df.

My current code for a single iteration (no loops) is like this:

```
dfA = 1
dfA_1 <- subset(df, A == dfA)
:: some ddply commands on dfA_1 altering its length and content ::
```

EDIT: to clarify, in the single iteration version, once I have the subset, I have been using ddply to then count the number of rows that contain some values. Not all subsets have all values, so the result can be of variable length. Thus, I have been appending the result to a skeleton df that accounts for cases in which a certain subset of df might not have any rows containing the values I expect (i.e., nrow = 0). Ideally, I wind up with the subset being fixed length for each instance of A. How can I incorporate this into a single (or multiple) plyr or dplyr set of code?

My issue with the for loops for this is that the length is not the variable, but rather the unique values of df$A.

My questions are as follows:
1. How would I use a for loop (or some form of apply) to perform this operation?
2. Can these operations be used to manipulate the data in addition to generate iterative df namess (e.g., the df named dfA_1 would be dfA_x where x is one of the values of df$A from 1 to 1000). My current thinking is that I'd then rbind the 1000 dfA_x's, though this seems cumbersome.

Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: The `dplyr` answer is nice and modern, but even regular old `plyr` replaces the need for loops and applies. If you're doing something to every level of `A`, then you `ddply(df, .variables = "A", ...)`. No need for subsetting in loops or any such nonsense.

Comment: In base R you could do something like `do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df,df$A),function(sub.df){...}))`. What do you mean "alter it's length and content"?

Comment: Currently, I've been using ddply to count nrow of some set of values, but since not all subsets contain all values, I've then been appending the result to a skeleton df of fixed length. I've added more information to the question above...please let me know if it's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You should really use the dplyr package for this.  What you want to do would probably take this form:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarize( . . . )
```

It will be easier to do, easier to read, less prone to error, and faster.

http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html